# multiple choice answer buttons in cshmtl (Razor)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor

I am developing a web application in cshtml (Razor/c# compatible html) which includes a "test section". This section has a question with 4 possible answers (only one being correct). At this point I retrieve the 4 answers from a record in a SQL database.

Then I need to set the display value of 4 different buttons to each of these values (or "assign" answers to buttons), in a randomly generated order.

(i.e. if the correct answer is in field 1 all of the time, I don't want the correct answer being the first button every time. It should move about.)

Any ideas, SO?

Comment: You could do something as simple as sorting the answers alphabetically. That should sufficiently randomize them.

Comment: Good point, but the 4 answers are in an individual record/row. Would I have to compare answer1 to answer 2 and so on to find the order, then add them or is there an easier way?

Comment: I would imagine you have to split them into separate entities anyway in order to assign them to buttons individually. It would be at that point a sort would be accomplished.